# CSS only rendering for my computer - production_environment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu

I have deployed my Rails application with Apache and can now see my project by visiting myappname.com . When I view the project from my personal computer in the browser it shows the application with the proper CSS, but when I view it from any other device, the CSS is not attached and the page is disassembled.

This is my first time deploying to an Ubuntu 16.04 droplet with Apache and am wondering if there is some configuration I missed setting up?

As this is my first time I didn't know which files I should post, so please just let me know if there is something I should check for and I will post it as well in an update.

**UPDATE:**

On my computer the CSS is occasionally not rendering background images but still has all other CSS code. Other devices still have no CSS rendering.

**UPDATE:**

It seems the Ubuntu server is trying to pull assets from localhost. The issue here is that I've hard coded my site to try and retrieve files from the local computer of whoever visits the site and not the server itself. Per the error I'm seeing:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/accordion.self-h3h497h7h34f7832987h4f8237h4f872h34f78923847fh82397h4f78h2348h3h4.css?body=1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Because it says "localhost" there, everyone who tries to load that page will try to load it with something on their local computer. So it's actually my computer that's listening on port 3000 in this case. I'll need to adjust how my site is coded so that it's pulling those CSS assets from itself and not localhost.

1 Problem: I have no idea how to do that. Will update again when I find a solution.

Comment: Did you precompile assets in your deployment box?

Comment: Yes I ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` from the root of the project on both my local environment and on the Droplet's.

Comment: In that case, can you show how you have apache and rails setup? Do you have rail's public directory as your document root? And lastly, how are you serving assets in production?

Comment: I am following this documentation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04. I have only done what it has directed. This is an example of CSS that is used inside a div-class container: `main_hero {background: url("/assets/myappname_hero_bg.png") no-repeat center center fixed;}`. This image will not show up in `<div class="main_hero">Hello World</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You must use the rails helpers in your scss files, `image_path` in this case

```
.main_hero {
  background: url(image_path("myappname_hero_bg.png")) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Comment: This broke the image on development, and did not work on production.

Comment: I am using .css, maybe that's why?

Comment: When I run `rails s` from the root of my project directory on my LOCAL computer, the images on the browser are viewable, but when I close the server, they are no longer visible! What is this sorcery?

Comment: Is the image in a subfolder?

Comment: And you must use `.scss` so the file gets compiled.

Comment: The image is in `app/assets/images`. Do I need to change all my CSS to SCSS?

Comment: Only if you're using some helpers, like `image_path`, but not if they're pure css files. I however always have all files as `scss` just to avoid issues like this.